# best JSON Structure and getData() in Service using Interfaces & Models for Nested JSON

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular5

I have tried to find solutions that I can understand with my knowledge level. But without success. I hope that others can benefit from this question.

Currently I am trying to understand how I provide data from different nested JSON files via interfaces and models. For my example, let's say I plan to have 3 JSON files in the future. (items.json, characters.json, monsters.json)

First, I'd like to find out what a clever JSON structure looks like. (There are many example tutorials, but I did not find any for such a special case as mine)

Which one is smarter?

**First variant:**

```
{
    "wearable": {
        "torso": [
            {
                "name": "Schlachtrobe",
                "defense": 7,
                "price": 22
            }
        ],
        "head": [
            {
                "name": "stirnband",
                "defense": 2,
                "price": 50
            }
        ],
        "wrist": [
            // etc...
        ]
    },
    "weapons": [
        // etc...
    ],
    "consumables": [
        {
            "name": "Bonbon",
            "effect": "Heilt um 100 TP"
        },
        {
            "name": "Schokolade",
            "effect": "Heilt um 250 TP"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Second variant:**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "category": "wearable",
        "type": "torso",
        "name": "Schlachtrobe",
        "defense": 7,
        "price": 22
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "category": "wearable",
        "type": "head",
        "name": "stirnband",
        "defense": 2,
        "price": 50
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "category": "consumables",
        "name": "Bonbon",
        "effect": "Heilt um 100 TP"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "category": "consumables",
        "name": "Schokolade",
        "effect": "Heilt um 250 TP"
    }
]
```

The second variant makes it easier to attach items (for example in the future monsters.ts) to other items. In this case, e.g. just attach the id numbers. But then each item must use the same interface structure ... Then, for example, the "Bonbon" of the category "consumable" always has an empty number field called "defense" And this is just a similar example. There will certainly be many more empty fields.

And what is about the interfaces and the Models? I try to solve this like this:

**items.interface.ts**

```
export interface ItemsInterface {

}

export interface ArmorsInterface {
    name: string;
    defense: number;
    price: number;
}

export interface ConsumablesInterface {
    name: string;
    price: number;
    effect: string;
}
```

**item.model.ts**

```
export class ItemsModel implements ItemsInterface {


}

export class ArmorsModel implements ArmorsInterface {

    name: string;
    defense: number;
    price: number;

    constructor(obj?: any) {
        this.name = (obj && obj.name) ? obj.name : '';
        this.defense = (obj && obj.defense) ? obj.defense : '';
        this.price = (obj && obj.price) ? obj.price : '';
    }

}

export class ConsumablesModel implements ConsumablesInterface {

    name: string;
    price: number;
    effect: string;

    constructor(obj?: any) {
        this.name = (obj && obj.name) ? obj.name : '';
        this.price = (obj && obj.price) ? obj.price : '';
        this.effect = (obj && obj.effect) ? obj.effect : '';
    }

}
```

**These could then be used in the service like this:**

```
@Injectable()
export class ItemsService {

    private items;
    private _armors: BehaviorSubject<ArmorsInterface> = new BehaviorSubject(new ArmorsModel());
    private _consumables: BehaviorSubject<ConsumablesInterface> = new BehaviorSubject(new ConsumablesModel());

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.loadItems();
    }

    get getArmors() {
        return this._armors.asObservable();
    }

    get getConsumables() {
        return this._consumables.asObservable();
    }

    loadItems() {
        this.http.get(`./assets/data/items.json`).subscribe((items: ItemsInterface) => {
            this.items = items;
            this._armors.next(new ArmorsModel(items));
            this._consumables.next(new ConsumablesModel(items));
        });
    }

}
```

There are certainly many mistakes in the service. I am still a beginner.

**And in the end how you could use the service:**

```
export class SiteHomeComponent implements OnInit {

    public armors: ArmorsInterface;

    constructor(private iS: ItemsService) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        // Returns the Data and write it in data
        this.iS.getArmors.subscribe((data) => {
            this.armors = data;
        });
    }

}
```

What can be done better? Or what would you do differently? I am grateful for everything that helps me to recognize my mistakes and to learn how to do it right. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: You can transform your models however way you like from behind your angular DataService. Do what makes sense for your UI (i.e. angular templates).  Hide all your transformation logic (if you have any) behind your DataService.  Avoid having transformation logic in your component class, or in your component template. Add a mapper layer (folder) to help your app scale that knows about your view models and your service models, and how to transform between them.

Comment: Thank you @pixelbits I hoped for a standard that makes sense to follow in this case. And what is about the rest of my Code? It looks like correct to you? In the loadItems() im not sure about how to implement the Interfaces and Models correctly here.